# Custom Button on new Opportunity Page that links to Visualforce Page on Save

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I've encountered a customers sandbox where the standard "Save" and "Save & New" buttons have been replaced by a "Save & Add Brand" button on the standard new opportunity page. They have renamed Opportunity Line Items as Brands and have renamed the Products tab as such.

When pressed, the button saves the Opportunity (after validation of required fields etc...) and then redirects the user to a custom Visualforce page for entering the Brand details. The Visualforce Page they arrive on is configured as the override for Opportunity Product standard button AddProduct.

[image: Salesforce New Opportunity Page with custom Save Button]

**How has the "Save & Add Brand" button been added to the New Opportunity page to replace the standard buttons?**

I need to add some additional buttons but can't find where it has been configured.

Under *Customize > Opportunities > Buttons and Links > Standard Buttons and Links* New is not showing any override. Also, if I add ?nooveride=1 to the URL I get the same page with the custom button. Edit has been overridden but that Visualforce page isn't the one being displayed to new (as expected).

There is no Detail Page Button on Opportunity with a label corresponding to this button.

Comment: I've posted the [same question on the developerforce discussion boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Custom-Button-on-new-Opportunity-Page-that-links-to-Visualforce/td-p/451255).

Comment: Have you checked the Page Layout to see if someone added a Custom Button?

Comment: @MatthewKeefe, when I used the Quick Access Menu to access the Page Layout from the New Opportunity page I'm taken to the Opportunity Detail page layout editor. There I can see all the custom buttons that appear on the Details page, but they aren't applicable to the "New Opportunity" page. I can't see anywhere to configure which buttons appears on the new page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Settings and disable "Prompt users to add products to opportunities"

Details: [Salesforce Help & Training: Prompting for Products on Opportunities](https://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_oppproduct.htm)

> Note: If enabled, replaces the **Save** button with a **Save & Add Product**
>   button [on] the opportunity creation page.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I've added a link in your answer to the online help for this feature.